Qt в новом проекте msvc не может открыть QMainWindow
При создании нового проекта Qt msvs и последующего его запуска выдаёт ошибку:

:-1: ошибка: dependent '............\Qt\6.7.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets\QMainWindow' does not exist.

Проверил, файл имеется. В чём проблема, не понимаю.

Может, у Вас где-то что-то с путем к файлу не так, если он его не находит?

@Anderbrine, в линуксе при наличии в пути до файлов символов круглых скобок '()' проект при сборке выдает то же самое. Проверьте пути. Никаких русских символов и желательно без служебных.

Имею ту же проблему. Конечного ответа нет, но получилось немного исследовать проблему.
Что сделал?

Создал чистый Qt проект с одним окном в папке C:\my\project_name. Каталог сборки: C:\my\project_name\build\debug
Попробовал собрать. Получил такую же ошибку:


C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
Error: dependent '..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\6.7.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets\QMainWindow' does not exist.
jom: C:\my\Repeater_2\build\debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
04:09:45: Процесс «C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe» завершился с кодом 2.

Теперь, если глянуть файл C:\my\project_name\build\debug\Makefile.Debug, то там можно найти такие строки:

compiler_moc_header_clean:
-$(DEL_FILE) debug\moc_MainWindow.cpp
debug\moc_MainWindow.cpp: ..\..\MainWindow.hpp 
..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\6.7.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets\QMainWindow 
..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\6.7.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets\qmainwindow.h 
..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\6.7.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets\qtwidgetsglobal.h \

То есть, если предположить, что рабочий каталог C:\my\project_name\build\debug, то в Makefile путь предполагается с большей вложенностью, нежели она есть на самом деле. Этот файл генерирует qmake. Видимо какая-то проблема в нём. Причём в других местах в файле путь правильный.
Что-либо сделать с этим у меня не получилось. По сути, только такие решения:

Отключить теневую сборку
Изменить путь сборки на C:\my\project_name (т.е. на корневую папку проекта) или на другую папку, уровень вложенности которой такой же, как и у корневой. Например: C:\my\project_name_build (по сути, как раньше оно работало).
Не использовать MSVC (проблема такая только с ним). Причём, Makefile не отличается особо, но видимо mingw32-make умеет лишнее сокращать, в отличие от jom.


Проблема с билдом msvc2019. Чтобы решить эту проблему установи себе MicrosoftVisualStudio на рабочий пк. Вместе с ним устанавливается этот билд по умолчанию.

В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению; на данный момент, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора. — из очереди проверок
